# Codify a measure in a database field name

Tags: database, language-agnostic, coding-style

I've got a question concerning fields in databases which are measures that might be displayed in different units but are stored only in one, such as "height", for example.

Where should the "pattern unit" be stated?. Of course, in the documentation, etc... But we all know nobody reads the documentation and that self-documented things are preferable.

From a practical point of view, what do you think of coding it in the database field (such as height_cm for example)?.

I find this weird at a first look, but I find it practical to avoid any mistakes when different people deal with the database directly and the "pattern unit" will never change.

What do you think?

Comment: I concur with Scott; what's wrong with naming the field such that the units in which the measurement is expressed are obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's weird about height_cm?  Looks good to me.

Sometimes you see measures and units in two separate fields, which is much more painful.

As long as you know the units aren't going to change, I think height_cm is a good way to deal with it.

Comment: Agreed, but I'd go a step further and be very clear.  If I saw "height_cm" I'd assume that they meant height in centimeters but I've been burned by screwy field names before and would certainly spent a few cycles confirming and second guessing.  Characters are cheap:  call it "height_in_centimeters"

Comment: Be sure to spell it correctly for who you expect to read or maintain it. 'Metre' is the scientific standard spelling, but 'meter' is the American spelling.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre

Comment: @TrickyNixon: Disagreed. Characters are not cheap. When there are STANDARDIZED abbreviations for units (or even very commonly used abbreviations) - I think it is a waste not to use them...

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support comments on columns. For example in Postgres you could set a comment like this:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN my_table.my_column IS 'cm';
```

Storing the unit name this way means your database is self-documenting.
I would also strongly recommend using standard scientific units (i.e. the metric system).

Comment: I wouldn't rely on a maintenance programmer to read the column comment!

Comment: Agreed, for such a small amount of data, go with 'height_in_centimetres' as the column name. but for more complex units such as "kilogram metres squared per second squared" I would definitely use the comments. And trust me, such units do occur.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, nothing wrong with adding the unit to the field name.

The only thing I'd say is to make the naming convention consistent across your database - i.e. avoid situations where you have both `height_cm` and `mm_width` present in the same database!

Answer (score 0):

Be wary about measures that may change like currencies. In many cases it is not practical rename database field when it's measure changes.

It is rather silly to have a field called `amount_mk` which used to contain money amount in marks but currently actually contains money amount in euros.